# Attaching kid trailer to rear triangle

Tags: mountain-bike, trailer

Have a cube aim sl MTB and a kid trailer that's designed to attach to the rear bottom side of the rear triangle with a clamp. The problem is that the clamp is not big enough to safely attach to the bottom side of the triangle since it's quite square and big, as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

Question: is it ok for the bike and trailer to attach the clamp to the seat stay since that tube is a lot slimmer.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the clamp and the area where you want to attach it ?  Otherwise it's hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Yes, please post some photos of how the hitch works on this trailer.  Along with how they fasten it to the tubing of the trailer.  My answer to this question is going to sound like a product req so I'll just put it here as a comment.  I have several trailers each with its own mounting system, but I was able to swap out all of that for a Burley flex connector system.  With the right pictures we I maybe able to tell you if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar trailer clamp it was terrible, I ended up buying a hitch that connects to the axle and removed the clamp. I attached a length of aluminum tubing with some holes drilled in it in place of the clamp. I slip the tube over the axle hitch and then use a hitch pin to keep it all in place. Its on my other bike currently but the hitch looks like this. I find this a way better system than the clamp.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I agree. A hitch like this will probably be my best option.

Comment: @Paul, that Kohl's link was broken, I suspect it had your login in it. Can you please paste a picture and optionally a working link?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find some other tube on the bike frame that fits the clamp better, that should be fine.  Obviously if you attach the clamp too high, the trailer will be tilted at an angle which would be uncomfortable for your kid.

I used to have a trailer with a similar attachment.  I noticed that the clamp can have a tendency to come loose from vibration, if it's not super tight. If the trailer doesn't already have it, I would rig up some kind of safety backup system, where a string/rope/bungee will hold the trailer arm if the clamp suddenly lets go. The idea is that you notice that something has happened to the trailer and you can pull over and fix it. It's not designed to keep riding without the clamp, except for 20-30 feet until you can stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these - it backed loose and fell off after 50 km.  The only thing saving it was the safety strap.

Clamp was tightened enough to chip most of the paint off the chainstay.  And that was with an empty trailer!   Imagine what would have happened had kids been in it?

Now I check the clamp every 10 km, and I won't tow kids in it.

I intend on replacing the screw clamp with with a ball clamp and fitting a 1/2" towball to each of my bikes.